# How to create a label in TFS/TFVC using the REST API?

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I know how to create a label in TFVC from within Visual Studio. I know the REST API can query for labels. But how do I create a label using the REST API?

Microsoft documentation does not cover it: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/labels

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently we cannot create a label using the REST API, just as you mentioned, according to the official documents this feature is not supported.

However you can create a label using TFS API with [VersionControlServer.CreateLabel Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138611%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), See below sample for your reference:

- http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2011/06/14/tfs-api-part-38-create-label/
- https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/10043190/

Besides, you can also create a label with the [**Label Command**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/label-command-team-foundation-version-control)

eg:

The following example uses the scope option to apply a label to 314.cs.

```
c:\projects>tf label goodbuild@$/TeamProject1 314.cs
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, usable answer. However, the library you are pointing at may not be the most recent, last update is december 2015.On Nuget I found Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient, which is said to "These packages replace the traditional TFS Client OM installer and make it easy to acquire and redistribute the libraries needed by your app or service.". Can you give a bit insight information; what is what and what is most future-proof? My company is on TFS 2017 and we update often.

Comment: @arjan Yeah, you can use the Nuget package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient, I just provided the method. The method is also available for TFS 2017. For the packages, any version should be ok if just try creating the label. I recommend you using the Label command, for now it's the easiest way to create label expect in VS.